# Unable to split two values of a column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataset and I am trying to split the values of a column location. The dataset I have is:-
[Dataset I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1sYz.png)

The dataset have 56 null values so I get the indexes of those null values using below code:-

```html
nan = []
for i in range(len(data['location'])):
    if type(data['location'][i]) == float:
        nan.append(i)
```

Once done I ran an another loop:-

```html
for i in range(len(data['location'])):
    if i in nan:
        data['city'] = np.nan
    else:
        data['city'] = data['location'][i].split(',')[1]
```

This giving me an error saying,

```html
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15176/2022247788.py in <module>
      3         data['city'] = np.nan
      4     else:
----> 5         data['city'] = data['location'][i].split(',')[1]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Though it is giving me values but it's not giving correct values. As seen in the location first value is NaN so I want NaN in the city and the second value in the column is Canandaigua, NY so I wish to have NY in the city.

I also tried them to split directly using the below code:-

```
data[['town','city2']] = data['location'].str.split(',',expand=True)
```

but getting an error:-

```
ValueError: Columns must be the same length as key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this to get the city to another column

```
data['city'] = data.location.str.split(",").str[1]
```

This will return either the city, or NaN if not available

Edit: Try this then.

```
data['city'] = data[~data.location.isna()].location.str.split(",").apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x) == 1 else x[1])
```

This checks if length of the split string is just one then returns the string as is. If else, returns the second value.

Comment: Thank for the answer, it worked but I have a few values where I have single values which I want to add to the city. The above code gives me the requested value, but it gives me NaN where the, is not present.

location                   city
Canandaigua, NY NY
Elmhurst                NaN

I wish to have Elmhurst in the city.

Comment: So the values in the location column are either Nan or the city alone or both the city and country? or could it be the country only as well?

Comment: The value in the location contains NaN, or town, city. I only need a city in this case.

Comment: The edited code giving this error:
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

due to the NaN values in the dataset as it's considering that value as float.

Comment: @lalitjoshi How about now?

Answer (score 0):

This should work too

```
### Comma Condition
comma_condtn = (df['location'].str.contains(',')) & (df['location'].notna())

### Extract city
df.loc[comma_condtn, 'city_2'] = df['location'].apply(lambda x : str(x).split(',').pop())

### Condition without commas
df.loc[df['city_2'].isna(), 'city_2'] = df['location']
```